# Files.walkFileTree throws exception outside visitor methods when walking /proc

Tags: java, nio

As I understand it, the usual way of handling exceptions when walking a file tree using Files.walkFileTree is to implement some try/catch logic in your visitor implementation, for example by just silently ignoring any AccessDeniedExceptions and moving on to other files. But I think I have found a case where the call throws an exception from outside the visitor code, which makes it hard to do anything about it. The effect is that the whole file traversal crashes. And yes, it is happening while traversing the special /proc filesystem on linux.

Using the old Java API File.list(..) on the same path does not crash, it just silently returns an empty list.

My question is, is there a way to ensure that a permission problem like this doesn't interrupt the whole file traversal?

For this particular directory, my user seem to be the owner of both the folder and all its contents, as can be shown by:

```
thomas.larsson@anonymized $ sudo ls -la /proc/2662/map_files
total 0
dr-x------ 2 thomas.larsson thomas  0 mar  4 09:44 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 thomas.larsson thomas  0 mar  4 09:11 ..
lr-------- 1 thomas.larsson thomas 64 mar  4 12:39 7f67499df000-7f67499ea000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
...
```

This makes me think I won't be able to do anything in the preVisitDirectory method like inspecting the PosixFileAttributes to determine whether I can read this directory or not.

This is a junit snippet that reproduces the problem for me

```
package com.apa;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class Example {

   @Test
   public void testWalk() throws IOException {
      Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("/proc/2662/map_files"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
          @Override
          public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
              System.out.println("Visiting " + file);
              return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
          }
      });
   }

   @Test
   public void oldApi() {
      String[] list = new File("/proc/2662/map_files").list();
   }
}
```

The corresponding stacktrace is:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /proc/2662/map_files: Operation not permitted
   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.asIOException(UnixException.java:111)
   at sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream$UnixDirectoryIterator.readNextEntry(UnixDirectoryStream.java:171)
   at sun.nio.fs.UnixDirectoryStream$UnixDirectoryIterator.hasNext(UnixDirectoryStream.java:201)
   at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:198)
   at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:69)
   at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2600)
   at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2633)
   at com.klarna.filewatch.Example.walkTheWalk(Example.java:14)
   ...
```

Best Regards
/Thomas

Comment: Is there anyone who found the answer or a walk-around? I have the same problem only the message is different: "Invalid Argument" instead of "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score -1):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html the default behavior of the visitFileFailed method is to re-throw the exception.

You would want to override that method to handle the exceptions yourself.

Comment: Your answer is about a file which is under a visit but the question is about the parent flow which calls/manage the visit. Check the stack trace please. And there is no exception handling mechanism provided AFAIK.